# File uploading in asp.net permission error (Access denied to path x)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-6, permissions

I'm trying to upload some image files in my asp.net web app.

Server OS: Windows server 2003 and IIS 6

I granted write permission in IIS to root and destination folder and granted FullControl Access to this users IUSer_Mashinname, Asp.net user, network services,Everyone, and all other users to the web app root folder and upload destination folder, but there is "Access denied problem".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and used [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine that although my app pool was running under IIS_IUSRS (which had write and modify privs), it was impersonating IUSR.  Adding privs to IUSR fixed the problem